# LocalSessionFactoryBean cannot be injected as SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection

The injection of my `sessionFacotry` bean into my transactionManager bean failed. It seems that the sessionFactory bean type (i.e. `LocalSessionFactoryBean`) is not recognized as `SessionFactory` type by the container, and therefore it is not injected into the `transactionManager` bean.

My configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException{
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("db.driverClass"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("db.jdbcUrl"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("db.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setMaxConnectionAge(1800);
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(1800);
        dataSource.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);       
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public  LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(javax.sql.DataSource dataSource){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("db.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "0");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("c3p0.acquire_increment", "1");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

My stacktrace output :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in de.fruuts.web.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 21 more
Jun 16, 2017 5:10:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in de.fruuts.web.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 21 more

INFO  SessionListener - # flyway migration...
Jun 16, 2017 5:10:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class de.fruuts.web.listener.FlywayListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in de.fruuts.web.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `sessionFactory` for the `transactionManager`

```
@Bean(name="transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory); // <--
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: You can convert `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to `SessionFactory` by calling `getObject()` like `transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory.getObject);`